# Feature Detection Algorithms and Feature Descriptor Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-detection, feature-extraction

I came to know about the difference between a detector and descriptor from the posts of SO.

I would like to know the common word which represents both the feature detection algorithms and feature descriptor algorithms. Is there any word for representing those both by using a common word.

can I use feature point algorithms or feature pattern algorithms?

Please let me know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

In brief, feature is image pattern which neighborhood is different from neighborhoods of other features (for example by texture, or intensity). It is used for description of the image content for image retrieval and recognition purposes.

Feature descriptor is vector that robust for various changes for example for shifts, rotations, scales, illuminating variations. Descriptor is computed from pixels around feature point and is used for matching purposes. Feature matching is performed by comparing the descriptors using suitable similarity measure.

There are another variants of the term "feature" such as interest point, key point, local feature, feature point. I did not see the term "feature pattern" in the appropriate literature, but I think it is the same as the term "feature point" in your case.

There are a lot of algorithms for feature point detection and descriptor  computation depending on your aims. You can see the excellent article about feature point detection [Local Invariant Feature Detectors: A Survey](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1391082) and also the article in Wikipedia [Feature (computer vision)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_(computer_vision)).

Here are the some links to the articles explaining feature detection and descriptor computation: Wikipedia [Feature detection (computer vision)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_detection_(computer_vision)), OpenCV [Feature Detection and Description](http://docs.opencv.org/master/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_feature2d.html), Matlab [Local Feature Detection and Extraction](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/local-feature-detection-and-extraction.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a specific word for this. Feature extraction (algorithm) might be the closest idea. In such a situation, it might be better to state the expression you use, with its definition.

Beware that "feature" is more general than "feature point", while "feature pattern" isn't used AFAIK (or might designate a kind of meta-feature).